# Blast Particle Not Spreading to Fullscreen

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a blast into the whole screen and spread a wave kind of effect into my 2d game. But the blast particle effect not expanding the camera window and I have captured a screenshot at the right time to explain my problem properly.

[image]

As you are seeing, the particle-wave blast actually crosses the screen or camera area but in the actual game window, I can't able to see the same effect.
It gets limited the expansion within the same window.

Here is the particle settings that I have set:

[image]

Now I can't able to understand exactly what problem exists so please guide me into this.

Comment: I like the way the game looks, are you creating a devlog or something so i could follow along?

Comment: No, not exactly devlog but yes I was posting sometime on my youtube channel: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvmhdXyW3ks1aI0mo-1Fp2w

Comment: Any help into this??